# My PowerShell exceptions aren't being caught

Tags: powershell, exception, powershell-2.0

Powershell v2:

```
try { Remove-Item C:\hiberfil.sys -ErrorAction Stop }
catch [System.IO.IOException]
{ "problem" }
catch [System.Exception]
{ "other" }
```

I'm using the hibernation file as an example, of course. There's actually another file that I expect I may not have permission to delete sometimes, and I want to catch this exceptional situation.

Output:

```
output
```

and yet `$error[0] | fl * -Force` outputs `System.IO.IOException: Not Enough permission to perform operation.`

Problem: I don't see why I'm not catching this exception with my first catch block, since this matches the exception type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the Stop action PowerShell changes the type of the exception to:

```
[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]
```

So this is the what you should catch. You can also leave it out and catch all types.
Give this a try if you want to opearte on different excdeptions:

```
try 
{
    Remove-Item C:\pagefile.sys -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    $e = $_.Exception.GetType().Name

    if($e -eq 'ItemNotFoundException' {...}
    if($e -eq 'IOException' {...}
}
```

Comment: ahh ok, that makes sense about the errorpreference. So then what's the deal with the `catch [exceptiontype]` syntax? According to http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/11/hey-scripting-guy-march-11-2010.aspx, that's the way to do it...

Comment: Thats how you deal with terminating exceptions. Your was a non-terminating(which is why you specified erroraction to stop). That's why u have to use shay's solution.

Comment: Exactly. By the way, if you look at the article you'll see that the catch for [System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException] is not printing, only other values, such as for [system.exception] (which in my opinion is not necessary since all exceptions are of that type.

Comment: ok, that helps a lot. I'm going to use `-erroraction Stop` with try/catch blocks for each individual command/function that I am concerned about.

Comment: The Scripting Guy link is actually:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/03/11/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-trycatchfinally-in-windows-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

I like the Trap method for global error handling, as I wanted to stop my scripts if unhandled exceptions were occurring to avoid corrupting my data. I set ErrorActionPreference to stop across the board. I then use Try/Catch in places where I may expect to see errors in order to stop them halting the scripts. See my question here [Send an email if a PowerShell script gets any errors at all and terminate the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246512/send-an-email-if-a-powershell-script-gets-any-errors-at-all-and-terminate-the-sc)