# PowerShell: Catch Exception of Active Directory Cmdlets

Tags: powershell

I have a problem concerning Exceptions in Powershell. For some reason they don't get caught.

```
Try { 
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupToModify.ObjectGUID -Members $user
} Catch [ADIdentityNotFoundException] {
    #message goes here
}
```

when trying to add a user from a different Domain it outputs:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=user,OU=users,
OU=J2,OU=sites,DC=asia,DC=domain,DC=com' under: 'DC=europe,
DC=domain,DC=com'.
At myscript.ps1:753 char:14
+     $adMember = Get-ADUser $user
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=user...s,DC=com:ADUser) 
[Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId :
ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:
Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,
Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [My PowerShell exceptions aren't being caught](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648590/my-powershell-exceptions-arent-being-caught)

Comment: powershell will only catch terminating errors (you'll have to set $erroractionpreference to "STOP"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options. Use `-ErrorAction Stop` on each cmdlet you want to trigger an exception:

```powershell
Try { 
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupToModify.ObjectGUID -Members $user -ErrorAction Stop
} Catch [ADIdentityNotFoundException] {
    #message goes here
}
```

or specify `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` at beginning of PS session to achieve same result for all subsequent cmdlets.

Comment: I was having the same behaviour while Connect-AzAccount cmdlet, from AzAccounts, your suggestion allowed to trap the exception. Why is this happening?

Comment: @ccoutinho the default behaviour for PS is to silently continue rather than halt on errors(throw exceptions). See https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/professional-windows-powershell/9780471946939/9780471946939_using_the_dollar_erroractionpreference_v.html

Comment: I am confused, I was able to trap countless exceptions so far, this is the first time I had to pass this argument in order for the exception to be thrown. Any idea why I'm having this erratic behaviour?

Comment: @ccoutinho presumably it's your shell setup, `$ErrorActionPreference` might have been set to `"Stop"` in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this error handling guide from Hey Scripting guy, it really helped me understand ho to use catch statements.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/11/hey-scripting-guy-march-11-2010.aspx